# Can't create a project from the Rest API but I can be able to create one using the oc tool

Tags: openshift

Note that I am using the same token but for the API I am receiving the following error.

Return code: 403, response text: `{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"projects is forbidden: User \"xxxx\" cannot create projects at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"projects"}`

So my question is why can't I be able to use the API for project creation?

Comment: Try using `oc new-project <name> --loglevel=6`. This will give you the exact API commands that `oc` is running, so you can at least confirm there that you're doing the same thing

Comment: Thank you for this. Seems like the API i was using is different from the one used by `oc`.

Comment: Yeah, increasing the loglevel has always been my goto when trying to recreate what `oc` is doing. Good luck!

Comment: One more question.
Any idea to the question I have asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090174/does-openshift-origin-1-1-rest-api-allow-to-create-new-applications-based-on-tem

Comment: No luck there...it likely hasn't changed. Clayton is the best resource for those questions